# Difference between pandas functions: df.assign() vs df.reset_index()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, coding-efficiency

So lets say I have a DataFrame:

```
    stuff  temp
id             
1       3  20.0
1       6  20.1
1       7  21.4
2       1  30.2
2       3   0.0
2       2  34.0
3       7   0.0
3       6   0.0
3       2  14.4
```

And I want to drop the index; what method is better to use?

- There is `df.reset_index(drop=True)`, which is what I will usually use
- But there is also `df.assign(Index=range(len(df))).set_index('Index')`, which I don't usually use
- And, is there any other methods?

Well, I want to find the most efficient/best way to drop the index of a `pd.DataFrame`. Can you give me a clear explanation. I'm doing a efficient code-writing project and I want to know the best options. Thanks.

Comment: Your index here "id" looks like it has useful information, you probably want to move this index "id" into the dataframe as a column.  Do this. 'df = df.reset_index()`, you will get a new dataframe index as the default range index from 0 to len of the dataframe minus 1.

Comment: Ok, but if I had a useless column: lets say `name`, and I want to delete it (because id already identifies it), what would the difference be between the options: quicker/slower? reliable/non-reliable?

Comment: Why haven't you tried timing those methods?

Comment: I want to know if the methods are reliable as well, but good point.

Comment: I would always go with a built-in method instead of writing the code myself. In this case, `.reset_index(drop=True)` is the way to go. If you wanted to overwrite the index, then `.set_index` would be my choice, but there is no reason to `.assign` to the dataframe first. Simply create a new `pd.Index` (or subclass/equivalent) and pass that to `.set_index` directly.